# Attempting to add ellipsis overflow but to no avail

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in my application that looks like this:

```js
    var td = $('#text');
    td.append("<div msg style='color:red'>" + "apply ellipsis so it doesn't stretch the td" + "</div>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        div[msg] {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:20%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10%">Month</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Savings</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:10%" id="text">
                January
            </td>
            <td style="width:10%">
                Lorem ipsum dolor. 
            </td>
          </tr>
    
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

As can be seen I am appending a div in one of my td's.

I would hope to be able to add a text-overflow:ellipsis to the div, so that it doesn't stretch the td.

And would want the appended text to only be the width of the TD rather than stretching it.

I followED some documentation online and added the appropriate css settings but to no avail.

Any idea why it's not working..Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var td = $('#text');
    td.append("<div style='width:100px'><div msg style='color:red'>" + "apply ellipsis so it doesn't stretch the td" + "</div></div>");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        div[msg] {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:20%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:10%">Month</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Savings</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:10%" id="text">
                January
            </td>
            <td style="width:10%">
                Lorem ipsum dolor. 
            </td>
          </tr>
    
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

> Add a container to your div with specific width.

Comment: But what I do not want to hardcode the width, I'd want it to know that the width is whatever is the width of the td (in this case being 10%)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS property (on the table element) to force the widths so they don't grow: `table-layout: fixed`.

Add a overflow:hidden to hide the extending content. But much better for UX would be a scroll bar or allowing the overflow on a new line.

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow:scroll;
 /* overflow:hidden */ 
}
```

```html
<body>
    <table style="width:400px">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:20%;">Month</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td id="text">
                January Lorem ipsum dolor. 
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem ipsum dolor. 
            </td>
          </tr>
    
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```